# Does ELF or PE loader support sections for GPUs, or some OS have any plans in implementing this functionality?

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, elf, portable-executable

Does ELF or PE loader support sections for GPUs?

I mean special section type that would be recognized by OS which then would map it with GPU MCU (Memory Controller Unit) as well as with main MC table. I know APUs have single MC (at least for AMD APUs it is true). In this case the section should be recognized by OS and mapped by the OS using corresponding drivers to GPU memory. I know it is possible, because both Windows and Linux have graphics interface API.

I tried to search for these in ELF and didn't found. Documentation search does not show me anything related.

And now I wonder why. Since WDDM already does support graphics memory swapping, mapping of GPU memory section would extremely increase games load as all resources would be mapped by PE loader in Windows case. OpenCL resources might be loaded as well.

Probably kernel.org has plans to implement this? Or Microsoft have such plans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no section type in PE or ELF specifically dedicated for GPU or other devices and there is no loaders currently implemented that can map a section directly to video-memory.

Answer (score 0):

Sergei
I know that ELF file format can contain any data in section as like additional. Loaders have no support of direct GPU memory mapping yet so far

Answer (score -1):

> ELF or PE support sections for GPUs?

Both `ELF` and `PE` support arbitrary sections, so the direct answer is: yes.

Now, once you have embedded a "GPU section" inside an `ELF` file, you'll probably want to have a loader do something with that section. But your question provides no details on what you are actually trying to achieve, and so a more useful answer can't be provided.

Comment: It is absolutely clear that this question is about PE/ELF loader functionality that should map a section into GPU memory. But I have provided additional details for you.

Comment: @Sergei Your question is *far* from clear now, and was absolutely unclear before the edit.

Comment: if this seems unclear to you, then you may consider to get familiar with mentioned technologies but, please, do not downvote without exact reason. It is absolutely deterministic. What do you need to clarify there?

Comment: The question is about ability of loader, your answer is irrelevant.